# Page redirection going on favicon.ico in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I am writing a selenium test where I am checking UI and functionlity of website.In functionlity I am entering username and passoword in input block and want to click on sign in button.All thing is working fine except sign in button.The click is also happening but it will not redirect on right page. It always redirects on

> http://vma-dev.saas.trilogy.com/favicon.ico"
>   where 
>   http://vma-dev.saas.trilogy.com is my base url. I am using following code..
>   For login using following function..

```
public void getLogin() throws InterruptedException 
{
    enterTextValueByElementNameInWindow(getBaseElement(),AppConstants.Html_Id_Common_Text_User ,AppConstants.USER_VAL);
    //getBaseElement().keyUp(AppConstants.Html_Id_Common_Text_User,"m");
    enterTextValueByElementNameInWindow(getBaseElement(),AppConstants.Html_Id_Common_Text_PWD ,AppConstants.PASSWORD_VAL);
    //getBaseElement().keyUp(AppConstants.Html_Id_Common_Text_PWD,"3");
    clickByElementInWindow(getBaseElement(), AppConstants.Html_Id_Common_Btn_Text_SignIn, true);
    try
    {
        getBaseElement().wait(10000);
    }
    catch(IllegalMonitorStateException ie)
    {

    }

}
```

and for click on signIn button I am using following function..

```
public static void clickByElementInWindow(LoggingSelenium appWindow, String element, boolean waitForPageLoad) 
{
    LoggingAssert.assertTrue("Button Element " + element + " cannot be located",appWindow.isElementPresent(element), appWindow);
    LoggingAssert.assertTrue("Button Element " + element + " is not visible",appWindow.isVisible(element), appWindow);
    appWindow.click(element);
    appWindow.setSpeed("500");
    if (waitForPageLoad){
        // wait for page to be ready
        // appWindow.waitForPageToLoad(Integer.toString(AppConstants.APP_READY_TIME));

        // sometimes page doesn't get loaded even with waitForPageToLoad. Use sleep to be safe. 
        try
        {    
            Thread.sleep(AppConstants.APP_PAGE_LOAD_WAIT_TIME);    
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ie)
        {
            // do nothing
        }
    }
}
```

I am badly stucked here.Any help is appriciated.

Comment: Is dere any role of cookies in ur page if yes then firstly clean cookies from your browser then re run ur test case.

Comment: No ,there is no role of cookies.I have done that(clear cookie),but same thing is happening.Sometime the page redirects on right page but not everytime.